How to increase the max matches in elasticsearch pipeline enricher
PUT _ingest/pipeline/enrich
{
  "processors": [
    {
      "enrich": {
        "description": "Add Events to customer",
        "policy_name": "merge",
        "field": "contact_id",
        "target_field": "events",
        "max_matches": "128"
      }
    }
  ]
}

I am not able to increase the max_matches value. Please help me how to increase this value?

According to the documentation you can not increase it.

The maximum number of matched documents to include under the configured target field. The target_field will be turned into a json array if max_matches is higher than 1, otherwise target_field will become a json object. In order to avoid documents getting too large, the maximum allowed value is 128.

Source: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/enrich-processor.html
If you try to increase you will get this error:

"reason": "[max_matches] should be between 1 and 128"

